# When Called From UIActivityViewController WhatsApp Freezes After a Recipient Is Selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using `UIActivityViewController` to share my iOS app.

When WhatsApp is selected from the list of options, it takes me to the proper screen. I can move around, and all the buttons work.

However, once I select a recipient, WhatsApp freezes.

Does anyone know what's going on here? Has anyone encountered this bug before?

**EDIT (Code Added)**

Here's the code I'm using to call the `UIActivityViewController`:

```
- (void) sharePressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

NSString* shareText = @"Hello World!";

UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[shareText] applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];


NSLog(@"This method ran: sharePressed");
}
```

It's as basic as it gets. It works for everything except WhatsApp.

Comment: please add some code

Comment: @DarjiJigar I just added code. Thanks for any help you might offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error was actually an internal problem with either whatsapp or `UIActivityViewController` because my other apps that use `UIActivityViewController` couldn't share on whatsApp last night. This morning though, even though I didn't change anything in my code, everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
- (IBAction)shareButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    NSString *textToShare = @"Look at this awesome website for aspiring iOS Developers!";
    NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.codingexplorer.com/"];

    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[textToShare, myWebsite];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                   UIActivityTypePrint,
                                   UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                   UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                   UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darji, this is good code! I think the error was actually an internal problem with either whatsapp or uiactivityviewcontroller because my other apps that use UIActivityViewController couldn't share on whatsApp last night. This morning though, even though I didn't change anything in my code, everything works perfectly!

Comment: I am facing the same issue but still i haven't found any solution if you get any alternative plz share

Comment: @MilapKundalia if you want  custom library?

Answer (score -1):

I think is a bug in WhatsApp after yesterday update.

Update: You can send an NSUrl instead of NSString.