# How to share text and image(both) on whatsapp using UIActivityController : Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, whatsapp, uiactivityviewcontroller, file-sharing

```
UIImage * imageShare = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:trackImagePath]]];


NSURL *urlLink = [NSURL URLWithString:linkstr];

SharingActivityProvider * share = [[SharingActivityProvider alloc]initWithPlaceholderItem:@"Ghaneely Share!"];
share.sharelink = urlLink;
share.sharelinkText = shareString;



NSArray *objectsToShare = @[imageShare,share];

activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

   [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
```

I want to share `text` and `image` (both) on WhatsApp just like Android by using `UIActivityController`. It used to work before when I used share without `SharingActivityProvider`. But I need to post different text on facebook, twitter,etc ,hence I am using `ActivityProvider`(which I think should not be the problem). Now with the code above it is sharing only `image`. 
What could be the issue?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586973/when-called-from-uiactivityviewcontroller-whatsapp-freezes-after-a-recipient-is/36592380#36592380

Answer (score 1):

From this way you can share text and video to whatsapp :-

```
NSString *URLString=@"http://video.app.com/video.php?";

  NSURL *VideoURL=[NSURL URLWithString:@“URLString ”];



 NSMutableArray *activityItems= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:VideoURL,@"Hey, check out this video I've shared with you, it's awesome!", result1, nil];

 self.activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
 self.activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypePrint,
 UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
 UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
 UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
 UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,UIActivityTypeAirDrop];

[self presentViewController:self.activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

try this may be it will help you.